# Nested component is overriding the style of parent component?

Tags: css, styled-components

I'm trying to place a large white box within a colored background but I'm having an issue
where my nested component seems to be applying a margin to it's parent component and not just on itself. Here is the code for the two components:

Background.js:

```
const Background = styled.div`
    background: linear-gradient(
      to bottom right,
      ${props => props.theme.color_primary_light},
      ${props => props.theme.color_primary_dark});
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /* text color for all children */
    color: ${props => props.theme.color_grey_dark_2};
    min-height: 100vh;
`;
```

Container.js:

```
const Container = styled.div`
  max-width: 120rem;
  background-color: ${props => props.theme.color_grey_light_1};
  box-shadow: ${props => props.theme.shadow_dark};
  min-height: 50rem;

  /*This margin seems to be applied to the parent*/
  margin: 8rem auto;
`;
```

And this is how I'm calling them from within the main App.js component:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Background>
        <Container>
        </Container>
      </Background>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Now this is the effect I'm trying to achieve. However I only managed to recreate this by using pure HTML and CSS and it works as one would expect. Background and Container are both divs, and Container is the direct child of Background. The CSS I'm applying is the exact same as the styled-components I listed above.

[image: This is the effect I'm going for]

However, what I'm actually getting in the styled-components example is the following:

[image: actual]

It's a little hard to tell but there is an 8rem margin applied to the top which is effectively 
pushing *both* the Background and Container components down instead of just moving the Container down by 8rem within the Background.

I'm wondering if anyone knows why this is the case and what I should be looking out for in order to fix this. I've only been practicing CSS for the past month so this might be an obvious fix that I seem to be overlooking, however I just can't figure one out.

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured it out. In Container.js I meant to set the min-width property, not 'max-width'. These simple mistakes can be super annoying.